# Laravel complicated where and where

Tags: laravel

I have a query that gets me all users having some specific skills chosen on a html array of checkboxes, which values are the Ids in database for skills.

When you have for example Laravel and SQL skills, the search query should only return you if the user put laravel and sql or one of them, otherwise, you shouldn't be displayed.

What is happening now is the other way : When you select laravel OR sql, it will show you in users list, but if you select both, you won't, while you still have those skills. If I replace the where by orWhere, it goes fine, but will also show you as a relevant user even if we type another skill which you don't have.

Here is a part of my query :

```
->when(isset($data['skills']) and $data['skills'] != null, function ($query) use ($data){
                $query->whereHas('skills', function ($subQuery) use ($data) {
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($data['skills']); $i++){
                            $subQuery->where('skills.id', $data['skills'][$i]);
                    }
                });
            })
```

The for is simply for opening t
he array of skills sent from the front data.

Any help would be usefull. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['skills']); $i++) {
                    $query->whereHas('skills', function ($subQuery) use ($data, $i) {
                        $subQuery->where('skills.id', $data['skills'][$i]);
                    });
                }
```

Solution was to simply put the whereHas inside the loop, so that the condition is checked as new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit subtle here:

Here's what whereHas a related query would look like:

```
select * from skills
where (skills.foreign_id = related_table.id 
       or `id` = ? or `id` = ? ... -- This is the orWhere part
);
```

As you can see the or is always going to be true for everything that corresponds to that relationship id **or those skills** (even if they do not belong to that person) so basically everything that belongs to that person plus some more rows that will eventually get filtered.

What you should do is:

```
 ->when(isset($data['skills']) and $data['skills'] != null, function ($query) use ($data){
            $query->whereHas('skills', function ($subQuery) use ($data) {
                $subQuery->where(function ($subSubQuery) use ($data) {
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($data['skills']); $i++){
                            $subSubQuery->orWhere('skills.id', $data['skills'][$i]);
                    }
                });
            });
        })
```

This will result in a relationship query that looks like:

```
select * from skills 
where skills.foreign_id = related_table.id 
      and (`id` = ? or `id` = ?) -- orWhere is now wrapped in parentheses
```

You could of course always do:

```
->when(isset($data['skills']) and $data['skills'] != null, function ($query) use ($data){
   $query->whereHas('skills', function ($subQuery) use ($data) {
          $subQuery->whereIn('skills.id', $data['skills']);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I still have the same result

Comment: I just added the whole query, if it might help