# Laravel WhereIn as AND instead of OR

Tags: laravel

Let's say I got an array: `[2,3,4]`

(array length / amount of values in array changes so I cannot hardcode it with bunch of where's)

And I want to get only the items which include all of the values in array while querying a relationship.

I am aware of WhereIn and using it like so:

```
 ->whereHas('interests', function($query) use ($arrayIds) {
     $query->whereIn('interest_id', $arrayIds);
 })
```

But this is basically

```
orWhere()->orWhere->get();
```

How can I achieve behaviour of:

```
->where()->where()->get();
```

So that all values in array would have to match instead while using an array of id's?

Comment: When you say get `the items which include all of the values in array` what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Do you just want to get only the items with ids, 2, 3 and 4?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Only items with id's 2,3 and 4. Sorry about the bit bad explanation in question.

Comment: But how would a row have an id of 2 AND and id of 3 AND an id of 4? Is this an array in a json column?

Comment: Gave an bad example using id, going to edit it.

Comment: Is this for a related table? So for example, if you have a table of users and those users belong to many clubs, you want to get the user that is in club 2 AND club 3 AND club 4?

Comment: It is yes and that's correct. Precisely what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this with users and clubs. If a user can belong to many clubs, this will give you users that belong to club 2 AND club 3 AND club 4:

```php
$clubIds = [2,3,4];     // club IDs
$users = User::query(); // initialize the query

// loop over club IDs, and give a whereHas clause for each one
foreach($clubIds as $clubId) {
    $users = $users->whereHas('clubs', function($clubQuery) use ($clubId) {
        // specify "clubs.id" to avoid ambiguity
        $clubQuery->where('clubs.id', $clubId); 
    });
}

$users = $users->get(); // execute the query
```

Comment: Thank you! That indeed did the trick. Had no idea at all that we can "split" the query like that. Extremely useful information here for the future.

Comment: @EmJeiEn No problem! But please update your question to say that you wanted to query a related model, and put the name of the relation in your `whereHas` instead of the foreign key. It will be easier for people seeking similar answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need an AND on ids, but you can loop over the ids like so:

```
 ->whereHas('interest_id', function($query) use ($arrayIds) {
    foreach($arrayIds as $id){
        $query->where('id', $id);
    }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that actually earlier myself but it it always returned empty enven though I know 100% that there's matches. Though I think the right format would be foreach ($arrayIds as $arrayId) for the loop? :)

Comment: Hahaha. True, wrote some js in there. Could you check the query being executed here?

Comment: Yeah, happens to me often as well :). But I just retried it, unfortunately it does return empty results. First my first thought to try as well in the beginning.

Comment: So, check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849011/laravel-complicated-where-and-where

Comment: thanks, got it solved with @newUserName02's answer though :).